# Are there any CORS workaround without server side change in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, media-player, video.js

I am trying to access a publicily shared google drive video file from my react website , since google drive file is not a absolute downloadable file,I am trying to play google drive video with a Custom Player ,so before showing the video in the player , I need to extract absolute file url with an XHR request.But I cannot access googledrive.com with XHR beacause it will only get CORS errors.Is there a way to request other server domains from a client domain without any serverside changes?

Comment: The only way to spoof a request origin is through server-side code.

Comment: @WaisKamal - you don't have to spoof anything from a server since servers are not subject to CORS rules

Comment: @Bravo sometimes the same-origin policy is enforced by the server providing the content. In this case you have to spoof the origin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short Answer

No. It's impossible to get around CORS without modifying server-side code.

### Long Answer

CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) is a browser's way of letting developers connect to external APIs from your website.

But that is an obvious security risk, not all APIs are meant to be public. To fix this risk, CORS only allows you to communicate to servers that ***have CORS enabled***.

Unless the owners of the server suddenly decide to enable CORS, you cannot make a request from your website to the server.

### The only way

The only way to achieve your goal is to ***send the request from a server***. When making requests from server to server, there is no CORS (it only exists on browsers).

##### You would have to create a server yourself, make the request there, and send the response to the client.

Comment: thanks but that would add another tech stack for me to work with.

Comment: @Iwin moe hein I'm afraid that's the only way to do it. There's nothing that can be done to keep your tech stack intact.

Comment: thanks for your help , I got your point . There's no other way to bypass CORS.